# How to open native camera in Panorama mode in an android application or is there any way to open camera in Panorama mode using Android's CameraX API

Tags: android-camera, android-camera-intent, android-camerax, android-image-capture, 360-panorama-viewer

`I need to capture images in Panorama view in an android application. Are there any ways to achieve this by opening android device's native camera app in existing android app.Or is there any way to open camera in Panorama mode using Android's CameraX API.

I have already tried the following possible solutions:
1.
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_IMAGE_REQUEST);

This opens native camera with option to switch to Panorama mode (but Panorama mode is not displayed as default) but it allows for multiple image capture and not one image. Also, it stores captured images in gallery and not in the specific path.

2. I have also tried com.google.android.gallery3d but no luck

In Activity class
Intent res = new Intent();
String mPackage = "com.google.android.gallery3d";
String mClass = "com.google.android.apps.lightcycle.ProtectedPanoramaCaptureActivity";
res.setComponent(new ComponentName(mPackage,mClass));
startActivity(res);

3. I have also tried Google Vr SDK but no luck. It is unable to find required package class and I get errors.`